# Magento2 - How can possible Reorder Product wise?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, orders, magento2.2

I need **All order Product Items** in User My account section.

> How I can get All order items with selected options.

[image]

Comment: Get the ordered item collection of user, Filter the ordered item collection. Use  ID's for Fetching the product details in displaying item in grid.

Comment: can you post your answer in code so I can give you +1 point.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you out

Create a custom block and add this code :

```
<?php
namespace Company\Slider\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_orderModel;   
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $orders;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderModel,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
        )
        {       
            $this->_orderModel = $orderModel;
            $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        public function getOrderItems($orderId) 
        {
            $order = $this->_orderModel->load($orderId);
            return $order->getAllVisibleItems();        
        }

    public function getUserId()
    {   
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) { 
            return $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        }
    }

    public function getOrders($customerId)
    {

        if (!$this->orders) {
        $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)->setOrder('created_at','desc');
        }
        return $this->orders;
    }
}
```

Create a template file and put code in it

```
<?php
$customerID = $block->getUserId();
$orderCollection = $block->getOrders($customerID);
foreach($orderCollection as $order){    
    $items = $block->getOrderItems($order->getId());     
    foreach ($items as $item) {     
        $options = $item->getProductOptions();        

        if (isset($options['options']) && !empty($options['options'])) {        
        foreach ($options['options'] as $option) {
            echo 'Title: ' . $option['label'] . '<br />';
            echo 'ID: ' . $option['option_id'] . '<br />';
            echo 'Type: ' . $option['option_type'] . '<br />';
            echo 'Value: ' . $option['option_value'] . '<br />' . '<br />';
        }
        }
    }
}
```

This code work for me, hope so works for you too.

For reference check the links

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-products-custom-option-value-from-cart-order/

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-load-product-by-id-and-sku/

Sorry for late replay

Thanks

Comment: you can check the product details also use this code : echo "<pre>";print_r($item->getData())

Comment: two order config product but same options don't skip any idea?

Comment: can you elaborate your ques?

Comment: Ex- Order -111 in one Simple product Custom option- Color - red,   another one Custom option Color - green so no need to skip but same option selection need to skip.

Comment: you need to customize the code for that

Comment: can you post code for config product?